# MPI -Scatterv increasing segmentation order

Tags: mpi

I would like to partition a vector in different size vectors by `MPI_Scatterv`. When I choose a partition made in decreasing order the code runs ok, but when I choose an increasing order, it fails fails.
Is it possible that `MPI_Scatterv` is used only for partitioning in decreasing order? I don't know where the error is. The code that is ok and the variation that is wrong follow.

```
program scatt
   include 'mpif.h'
   integer idproc, num, ierr, tag,namelen, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE),comm
    character *(MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME) processor_name
    integer, allocatable :: myray(:),send_ray(:)
    integer counts(3),displ(3)
    integer siz,mysize,i,k,j,total
   call MPI_INIT(ierror)
    comm = mpi_comm_world
   call MPI_COMM_SIZE(comm, num, ierror)
   call MPI_COMM_RANK(comm, idproc, ierror)

    siz=12
! create the segmentation in decreasing manner
    counts(1)=5
    counts(2)=4
    counts(3)=3
    displ(1)=0
    displ(2)=5
    displ(3)=9
   allocate(myray(counts(idproc+1)))
myray=0
! create the data to be sent on the root
    if(idproc == 0)then
        !size=count*num
        allocate(send_ray(0:siz-1))
        do i=0,siz
            send_ray(i)=i+1
        enddo
        write(*,*) send_ray
    endif
! send different data to each processor
    call MPI_Scatterv(  send_ray, counts, displ, MPI_INTEGER, &
                        myray, counts,  MPI_INTEGER, &
                        0,comm,ierr)
    write(*,*)"myid= ",idproc," ray= ",myray
   call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
   end
```

Result ok is:

```
myid=            1  ray=            6           7           8           9
myid=            0  ray=            1           2           3           4           5
myid=            2  ray=           10          11          12
```

When I write the same code in increasing segmentation order

```
 counts(1)=2
 counts(2)=4
 counts(3)=6
 displ(1)=0
 displ(2)=2
 displ(3)=6
```

The segmentation is made only for the root

```
 myid=            0  ray=            1           2
```

and the error message is:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Scatterv: Message truncated, error stack:
PMPI_Scatterv(671)......................: MPI_Scatterv(sbuf=(nil), scnts=0x6b4da0, displs=0x6b4db0, MPI_INTEGER, rbuf=0x26024b0,
rcount=2, MPI_INTEGER, root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Scatterv_impl(211).................: 
I_MPIR_Scatterv_intra(278)..............: Failure during collective
I_MPIR_Scatterv_intra(272)..............: 
MPIR_Scatterv(147)......................: 
MPIDI_CH3_PktHandler_EagerShortSend(441): Message from rank 0 and tag 6 truncated; 16 bytes received but buffer size is 8
Fatal error in PMPI_Scatterv: Message truncated, error stack:
PMPI_Scatterv(671)................: MPI_Scatterv(sbuf=(nil), scnts=0x6b4da0, displs=0x6b4db0, MPI_INTEGER, rbuf=0x251f4b0, rcount=2, MPI_INTEGER, root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Scatterv_impl(211)...........: 
I_MPIR_Scatterv_intra(278)........: Failure during collective
I_MPIR_Scatterv_intra(272)........: 
MPIR_Scatterv(147)................: 
MPIDI_CH3U_Receive_data_found(131): Message from rank 0 and tag 6 truncated; 24 bytes received but buffer size is 8
forrtl: error (69): process interrupted (SIGINT)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code.

First, the invocation of `MPI_Scatterv` is wrong. The size of the receive buffer must be a scalar, not an array, and give the size of the array in the calling rank only. In your case you need to change the second occurrence of `counts` to `counts(idproc+1)`:

```
call MPI_Scatterv(send_ray, counts, displ,    MPI_INTEGER, &
                  myray,    counts(idproc+1), MPI_INTEGER, &
                  0, comm, ierr)
```

The same applies to the complimentary operation `MPI_Gatherv` - there the size of the local send buffer is also a scalar.

Another problem is the out-of-bounds access in this initialisation loop:

```
    allocate(send_ray(0:siz-1))
    do i=0,siz
        send_ray(i)=i+1
    enddo
```

Here `send_ray` is allocated with bounds `0:siz-1`, but the loop runs from `0` to `siz`, which is one element past the end of the array. Some compilers have options to enable run-time out-of-bound access checks. For example, with Intel Fortran the option is `-check bounds`. For Gfortran the option is `-fcheck=bounds`. Accessing arrays past their end could overwrite and thus alter the values in other arrays (worst case, hard to spot) or destroy the heap pointers and crash your program (best case, easy to spot).

As Gilles Gouaillardet has noticed, do not use `mpif.h`. Instead, `use mpi` or even better `use mpi_f08` should be used in newly developed programs.

Comment: also, since `MPI` tasks start at zero, you might want to have the `counts` and `displs` arrays start at index zero (and update the rest of the code accordingly) to improve readibility (e.g. `counts(i)` is the count for MPI task `i`). In the same spirit, `send_ray` might start at default index `1`, unless there is some value in having start at index `0`.